# memcached installation error

Tags: php, memcached, pecl

when i try to install memcached in **windows xp** with **xampp** by command line as the follow:

`pecl install memcached`

i recive this error in my command window :

`Error : The DSP memcached.dsp does not exist.`

1 - what is the problem ?

2 - and if its not solvable how to compile the memcached package when 
download it directly from the pecl ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might [look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048309/pecl-extesions-for-windows) for a related problem.  It looks like there are limited extensions available for PHP Windows, and `memcached` has probably not been built for pecl4win.

There is [a link](http://downloads.php.net/pierre/) on the other question on how you can build your own PHP on Windows, or else you might ask if someone else could make a build on the mailing list:  pecl-dev at lists.php.net