# Error: The DSP phar.dsp does not exist, when trying to install php_phar via pecl

Tags: php, windows, php-5.3, pecl, phar

I received this error when trying to install php_phar on php 5.3.8 / windows7 x64 via pecl:

```
pecl install phar
```

(I don't have php_phar.dll in my extensions directory).

Can't google anything about this problem.

Comment: It looks like you may be out of luck and have to build the extension DLL yourself: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048309

Answer (score 1):

pecl install is not support on Windows.

However phar is not maintained anymore via PECL but in the PHP core. It is bundled as part of PHP 5.3 or later.